# Fourier transform software

Tags: charts, analysis

After spending a lot of time searching for this, I thought that some Super User gurus might know the answer. I'm searching for an open source application to compute a FFT, that could:

- Import a list of points from a text file (in any format; I could write conversion scripts if needed), for example `0,1; 1,2; 4,5`
- Compute the associated discrete transform, and output the list of coefficients

Ideally, it would also display the plot and the associated fourier decomposition on the same graph, to allow comparison, but this is not absolutely needed.

It can be either on Windows or on Linux/UNIX.
Can you think of a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

::pokes around the internet a little::

- In [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) its called [`fft`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Signal-Processing.html#Signal-Processing).
- In [R](http://www.r-project.org/) its called [`fft`](http://ugrad.stat.ubc.ca/R/library/stats/html/fft.html)
- In [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/) it's supported in the MathMore module which calls [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/). You access it from the [TH1::FFT](http://root.cern.ch/root/html526/TH1.html#TH1:FFT) (and daughters) or through the interfaces in [TVirtualFFT](http://root.cern.ch/root/html526/TVirtualFFT.html) (though this claims to call [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/), so I'm a little confused).

and I believe that all those tools support plotting as well.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I can load curves from files into Octave?

Comment: I don't use octave. In my business the all-singing-all-dancing tool of choice is root.

Comment: Using the "load" command, see e.g. http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Simple-File-I_002fO.html

Comment: Tanks! That seems to work :)

Answer (score 1):

Python has some libraries for this, e.g. try [scipy's fft module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html). You could then use the [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) module for plotting. To get the data from the input you could use either plain Python or [numpy's loadtxt](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc#head-88ade192dacf0c15e4f1377096134ee559df07a0) which opens up potential for a whole lot of other processing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out SciLab. I used that in my Control Systems class to take the place of MatLab since I didn't have a university laptop. I'm not sure if it does exactly what you're asking, but check it out, it pretty full-featured and open source/ free! Lol